# do I need to download the subversion binaries to use SmartSVN?

Tags: windows, svn, smartsvn

I'm using windows 7 64 bits and I want to know if I need the subversion binaries to use smartsvn.. waiting for answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SmartSVN uses SVNKit library to work with Subversion and includes it into its distribution. No binaries are required.

Comment: I think you won't be able to use command-line options, though. TortoiseSVN and SlikSVN both do that job.

Answer (score -3):

smartsvn is the server, you'll need something like http://tortoisesvn.net/ on your windows machine to connect to the smartsvn service.